# how to hide warp-cli top bar icon

Tags: top-bar

i have this annoying warp-cli top bar icon on the Dash to Panel (normally on top bar)
[warp-cli icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QH7E.png)

**it indicates warp-cli status but i want to hide it.
how i can do it? please help me.**

Using Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS, Gnome 42 for Extensions.

*additional info (https://community.cloudflare.com/t/warp-taskbar-icon-on-a-linux-desktop/377862)*

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using.? If there is important info at that link please include it in the question so people do not have to chase after it.

Comment: David, i use ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how to delete warp-taskbar from top-bar. Go to /bin/ as administrator, select properties of warp-taskbar and disable allowing executing as program, then go to system monitor and kill warp-taskbar process so it isn't restarts!

And now i have this nice looking icon.

[my top-bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF02V.png)